# How to make flatpickr datepicker reactive in livewire / alpinejs app?

Tags: flatpickr, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

In my laravel 7 /livewire 1.3 / alpinejs 2 project
I added flatpickr datepicker from https://flatpickr.js.org
datepicker works ok, but reactive does not work. In the code below
$current_operation_date - public var in the component and is is modified ok
but alpine var operation_date is not changed when in datepicker value is selected:

```
<div>        
    $current_operation_date::{{$current_operation_date}}<BR>
    operation_date::<div x-html="operation_date"></div>
    <!-- The line above is not modified when in datepicker value is selected -->

    <div x-data="{ operation_date: '{{$current_operation_date}}'}">
        <input
            type='text'
            id="flatpickr_operation_date"
            wire:model.lazy="current_operation_date"

            x-model="operation_date"
            x-on:blur="$dispatch('input', operation_date)"
            class="form-control editable_field"
        />
    </div>

</div>


@section('scripts')
    <script>


        $(document).ready(function(){

            var fp = flatpickr(document.querySelector('#flatpickr_operation_date'), {
                enableTime: false,
                dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
                altFormat: "F j, Y",
                altInput: true,
                inline: false,
                locale: "es",
                "minDate": "2020-7-12",
                "maxDate": "2020-9-12",
                defaultDate: ["2020-9-10"],
                onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                    console.log('selectedDates::')
                    console.log(selectedDates) //valid
                    
                    console.log('date: ', dateStr);
                }
            });

        });
    
    
    
    </script>
@endsection

<style>
   ...
```

If there is a way to make it reactive ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the TALL stack with Livewire 2.7, alpine 3.4 and Laravel 8
This is my current solution

**components/inputs/date.blade.php**

```php
@props(['options' => []])

@php
    $options = array_merge([
                    'dateFormat' => 'Y-m-d',
                    'enableTime' => false,
                    'altFormat' =>  'j F Y',
                    'altInput' => true
                    ], $options);
@endphp

<div wire:ignore>
    <input
       x-data="{
           init() {
               flatpickr(this.$refs.input, {{json_encode((object)$options)}});
           }
        }"
        x-ref="input"
        type="text"
        {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-input w-full rounded-md shadow-sm']) }}
    />
</div>
```

Then I'm using it like this:

```php
<x-inputs.date id="flatpickr_operation_date" wire:model="current_operation_date" />
```

---

### bidirectional

To go deeper, when we want to dynamically change the date from the Livewire component and we want the date to be updated in flatpickr as well, here's my current solution

---

here's my current solution

```php
@props(['options' => []])

@php
    $options = array_merge([
                    'dateFormat' => 'Y-m-d',
                    'enableTime' => false,
                    'altFormat' =>  'j F Y',
                    'altInput' => true
                    ], $options);
@endphp

<div wire:ignore>
    <input
        x-data="{
             value: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')), 
             instance: undefined,
             init() {
                 $watch('value', value => this.instance.setDate(value, false));
                 this.instance = flatpickr(this.$refs.input, {{ json_encode((object)$options) }});
             }
        }"
        x-ref="input"
        x-bind:value="value"
        type="text"
        {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-input w-full rounded-md shadow-sm']) }}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how I can use the locale with this code? For example Bulgarian language.

Comment: There 2 ways; **1**) You can [set the locale globally](https://flatpickr.js.org/localization/#using-modules)  **2**)  [add the locale](https://flatpickr.js.org/localization/#localization-in-a-browser-environment);  then in the `array_merge` add `'locale' => 'bg'` _note:_ You can override the locale  `<x-inputs.date :options="['locale' => 'bg']" wire:model="date"/>`

Comment: when I use `wire:model="employee.date"` it is not working.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan Does `date` exists on your array ? If yes, please, do open a new SO question with a reproducible example.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier, thank you for quick reply, date was not set in component that cause issue

Comment: Hi @ClémentBaconnier how can we use events in the options?

Comment: @burf Sorry for the late answer. `{{ json_encode((object)$options) }}` will return a Javascript object. I would merge the javascript object with your events: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically 
Or you can not use `$options` at all. it's up to you.

Comment: For somereason the bidirectional example is not working for me with livewire 3.
The input doesnt open the flatpickr popup anymore. The other example works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @Hese, I just tried bidirectional with a fresh Laravel / Livewire 3 installation and worked as expected. Try creating a new question on SO with the errors you gets